# How to display the min and max elements of an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I've been trying to solve this problem for quite some time now. I'm trying to display the min and max elements of an array, but the min always remains at 0. Here's the code that explains my issue:

```
public class ArrExs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("enter the array capacity (min 1, max 20): ");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        while(n <= 0 || n > 20) {
            System.out.print("enter a valid number and try again: ");
            n = input.nextInt();
        }
        int[] nums = new int[n];
        maxAndMin(nums);
    }
    public static void maxAndMin(int[] numbers) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter your array elements: ");
        int min = numbers[0];
        int max = numbers[0];
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
            max = (numbers[i] > max) ? numbers[i] : max;
            min = (numbers[i] < min) ? numbers[i] : min;
        }
        System.out.print("min = " + min + ", max = " + max);
    }
}
```

The output:

```
enter the array capacity (min 1, max 20): 3
enter your array elements: 
2
3
4
min = 0, max = 4
```

The min always remains at 0, I've tried to edit the code multiple times but I get the same result.

Comment: try initializating min to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and max to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` .

Comment: you are initializing min value with int min = numbers[0]; and number[0] equals 0 at that point so you can't have value which is lesser than 0 in your typed values 2,3,4. Like @MiguelLuna said initialize values with int max and int min values

Comment: why do you have a nextInt in your maxAndMin method? you should already have your values, this makes no sense. But, indeed, your problem is that you are comparing those values against 0. Either initialize that value to Integer.MIN_VALUE, or to the first element of your array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding a minimum and maximum value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47383316/finding-a-minimum-and-maximum-value-in-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem before and watched a video where the instructor's logic is to set the "Min" and "Max" to the first number entered by the user. Then there comes the relational operator to decide which is minimum and maximum.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the line where you do `int min = numbers[0];` because `numbers` is an empty array (all of the values are 0).  Since `min` starts at 0 and nothing in the array is less than 0 then min will remain 0 forever.

Try making `min` start as a high value such as `int.MaxValue` and see if that fixes your problem.